# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on accessing NSButton subclass property from view controller

Tags: swift, cocoa

I'm attempting to access a NSButton subclass property from a view controller, but receive the following error at the HoverButton's setImages method:

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, adress=0x0)

It seems I'm losing reference, but I'm not sure how to maintain reference. (Still very fresh to Swift & OS X dev)

In my view controller:

```
@IBOutlet weak var newAccountButton: HoverButton!
@IBOutlet weak var joinAccountButton: HoverButton!
...
let off = NSImage(named: "button-off")!
let over = NSImage(named: "button-over")!
newAccountButton.setImages(imageOriginal: off, imageHover: over)
joinAccountButton.setImages(NSColor.clearColor(), imageOriginal: off, imageHover: over)
```

...

```
class HoverButton: NSButton {

    var trackingArea:NSTrackingArea!
    var hoverBackgroundImage: NSImage!
    var originalBackgroundImage: NSImage!


    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {

        super.init(frame: frameRect)

        // set tracking area
        trackingArea = NSTrackingArea(rect: bounds, options: [NSTrackingAreaOptions.MouseEnteredAndExited, NSTrackingAreaOptions.ActiveAlways], owner: self, userInfo: nil)
        self.addTrackingArea(trackingArea)

    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)

        // set tracking area
        trackingArea = NSTrackingArea(rect: bounds, options: [NSTrackingAreaOptions.MouseEnteredAndExited, NSTrackingAreaOptions.ActiveAlways], owner: self, userInfo: nil)
        self.addTrackingArea(trackingArea)
    }

    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.drawRect(dirtyRect)
    }

    override func mouseEntered(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        let cell = self.cell as! NSButtonCell
        cell.image = hoverBackgroundImage

    }

    override func mouseExited(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        let cell = self.cell as! NSButtonCell
        cell.image = originalBackgroundImage
    }

    func setImages(imageOriginal: NSImage, imageHover: NSImage) {
        self.originalBackgroundImage = imageOriginal
        self.hoverBackgroundImage = imageHover
    }

}
```

based off https://github.com/Swift-Kit/JZHoverNSButton (use of which gives same error)

Comment: Do `off` or `over` contain nil?

Comment: No, both images are being referenced fine.

Comment: In that case it's probably `newAccountButton` that is nil. Can you confirm that it's hooked up properly in Interface Builder? Since you've based the code from github, could it be that you've done a copy/paste but not hooked up the IBOutlets?

Comment: No, the buttons are connected properly too (I'm changing their Titles programmatically which works fine).

Comment: Why are you allowed to say `setImages(NSColor.clearColor(), imageOriginal: off, imageHover: over)`? Is there another `setImages` method in HoverButton that you have forgotten to show us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have no outlets from HoverButton instances in the nib or storyboard to your `newAccountButton` and `joinAccountButton` properties.

Comment: I have references in the view controller - this isnt sufficient? I'm not using storyboard (developing for 10.9) .

Comment: Read my answer carefully. They may have outlets but you forgot to specify in the nib that they are HoverButtons. Or they may have no outlets. Either mistake will get you a crash.

Comment: Oh dear... I neglected to change the class to HoverButton in Interface Builder. Thanks so much!